# How to Change the Background Color of the Row by Right Clicking

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

When I right click one of the rows in the table a menu should appear AND the background of the row will be changed into a yellow color. At the same time when you remove the menu, the background color should be changed into default color.

In addition, when you right click on the next row, the previous and selected row should be changed into a default color.

I do not know how to do it.

```js
$(function() {

    var $contextMenu = $("#contextMenu");

    $("body").on("contextmenu", "table tr", function(e) {
         $contextMenu.css({
              display: "block",
              left: e.pageX,
              top: e.pageY
         });
         return false;
    });

    $('html').click(function() {
         $contextMenu.hide();
    });

});
```

```css
#contextMenu {
  position: absolute;
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <link href="http://getbootstrap.com/dist/css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
  <script src="http://getbootstrap.com/dist/js/bootstrap.js"></script>

  <link href="http://getbootstrap.com/2.3.2/assets/css/bootstrap-responsive.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
  <meta charset=utf-8 />
  <title>JS Bin</title>
</head>

<body>

  <table id="mt" class="table">
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th>#</th>
        <th>First Name</th>
        <th>Last Name</th>
        <th>Username</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>Mark</td>
        <td>Otto</td>
        <td>@mdo</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>2</td>
        <td>Jacob</td>
        <td>Thornton</td>
        <td>@fat</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>3</td>
        <td>Larry</td>
        <td>the Bird</td>
        <td>@twitter</td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>

  <div id="contextMenu" class="dropdown clearfix">
    <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu" aria-labelledby="dropdownMenu" style="display:block;position:static;margin-bottom:5px;">
      <li><a tabindex="-1" href="#">Action</a>
      </li>
      <li><a tabindex="-1" href="#">Another action</a>
      </li>
      <li><a tabindex="-1" href="#">Something else here</a>
      </li>
      <li class="divider"></li>
      <li><a tabindex="-1" href="#">Separated link</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Table header also gets highlighted, is that part of requirement?

Comment: Table header also gets highlighted, is that part of requirement?

Comment: I would not like to be happened, Thank your for your attention.

Comment: Kindly have a look at my answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Following is the answer for your question.

Use `$(this).css("background-color", "yellow");`

Here:

```
$("body").on("contextmenu", "table tr", function(e) {
             $contextMenu.css({
                  display: "block",
                  left: e.pageX,
                  top: e.pageY
             });
             $('table tr').css("background-color", ""); //Remove previos color.
              $(this).css("background-color", "yellow"); //Here Change color to yellow.
             return false;
        });
```

And back to default:

```
$('html').click(function() {
            $('table tr').css("background-color", ""); //Back to Default 
             $contextMenu.hide();

        });
```

Check

```js
$(function() {

    var $contextMenu = $("#contextMenu");

    $("body").on("contextmenu", "table tr", function(e) {
         $contextMenu.css({
              display: "block",
              left: e.pageX,
              top: e.pageY
         });
           $('table tr').css("background-color", "");
          $(this).css("background-color", "yellow"); 
         return false;
    });

    $('html').click(function() {
        $('table tr').css("background-color", "");
         $contextMenu.hide();
     
    });
  
  

});
```

```css
#contextMenu {
  position: absolute;
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <link href="http://getbootstrap.com/dist/css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
  <script src="http://getbootstrap.com/dist/js/bootstrap.js"></script>

  <link href="http://getbootstrap.com/2.3.2/assets/css/bootstrap-responsive.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
  <meta charset=utf-8 />
  <title>JS Bin</title>
</head>

<body>

  <table id="mt" class="table">
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th>#</th>
        <th>First Name</th>
        <th>Last Name</th>
        <th>Username</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>Mark</td>
        <td>Otto</td>
        <td>@mdo</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>2</td>
        <td>Jacob</td>
        <td>Thornton</td>
        <td>@fat</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>3</td>
        <td>Larry</td>
        <td>the Bird</td>
        <td>@twitter</td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>

  <div id="contextMenu" class="dropdown clearfix">
    <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu" aria-labelledby="dropdownMenu" style="display:block;position:static;margin-bottom:5px;">
      <li><a tabindex="-1" href="#">Action</a>
      </li>
      <li><a tabindex="-1" href="#">Another action</a>
      </li>
      <li><a tabindex="-1" href="#">Something else here</a>
      </li>
      <li class="divider"></li>
      <li><a tabindex="-1" href="#">Separated link</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>

</body>

</html>
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: I have added an additional requirement. Please take a look.

Comment: @HelloWorld Edited my answer with you edited question. *"when you right click on the next row, the previous and selected row should be changed into a default color."*

Comment: I have another question. Today, I'm newbie in web development and what recommended tool do you use when you create CSS,jQuery, html etc?

Comment: @HelloWorld For development use dreamviewer editor and use developer tool firebug.

Answer (score 0):

```
$(function() {

    var $contextMenu = $("#contextMenu");

    $("body").on("contextmenu", "table tr", function(e) {
         $contextMenu.css({
              display: "block",
              left: e.pageX,
              top: e.pageY

         });
        $('table tr').css('background','none');
        $(this).css('background','yellow');
         return false;
    });

    $('html').click(function() {
         $contextMenu.hide();
        $('table tr').css('background','none');
    });

});
```

[**DEMO Here**](http://jsfiddle.net/7a7xzn3n/)

Answer (score 0):

Try adding/removing class to tr:

```js
$(function() {

  var $contextMenu = $("#contextMenu");
  /* changed selector to target only tbody tr */
  $("#mt tbody tr").on("contextmenu", function(e) {
    $contextMenu.css({
      display: "block",
      left: e.pageX,
      top: e.pageY
    });
    $(this).addClass('selected').siblings().removeClass('selected'); //added this line
    return false;
  });

  $('html').on('click', function() {
    $contextMenu.hide();
    $("#mt tbody tr").removeClass('selected'); //added this line
  });

});
```

```css
#contextMenu {
  position: absolute;
  display: none;
}
/* added this class */

tr.selected {
  background: yellow;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <link href="http://getbootstrap.com/dist/css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
  <script src="http://getbootstrap.com/dist/js/bootstrap.js"></script>

  <link href="http://getbootstrap.com/2.3.2/assets/css/bootstrap-responsive.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
  <meta charset=utf-8 />
  <title>JS Bin</title>
</head>

<body>

  <table id="mt" class="table">
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th>#</th>
        <th>First Name</th>
        <th>Last Name</th>
        <th>Username</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>Mark</td>
        <td>Otto</td>
        <td>@mdo</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>2</td>
        <td>Jacob</td>
        <td>Thornton</td>
        <td>@fat</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>3</td>
        <td>Larry</td>
        <td>the Bird</td>
        <td>@twitter</td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>

  <div id="contextMenu" class="dropdown clearfix">
    <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu" aria-labelledby="dropdownMenu" style="display:block;position:static;margin-bottom:5px;">
      <li><a tabindex="-1" href="#">Action</a>
      </li>
      <li><a tabindex="-1" href="#">Another action</a>
      </li>
      <li><a tabindex="-1" href="#">Something else here</a>
      </li>
      <li class="divider"></li>
      <li><a tabindex="-1" href="#">Separated link</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>

</body>

</html>
```